How to ensure that a DocumentSnapshot and a QurySnapshot stream from a collection are in sync
I am using Firestore with Flutter with local persistence disabled. I have two clients A and B. Client A performs a batch write operation which includes:

Updating a document in the path users/uid with data {"lastChanged" : server timestamp }
Inserting, updating or deleting some documents in the collection users/uid/docList

Client B listens to the docList collection with a QuerySnapshotListener. I want to store the lastChanged field locally in sharedPreference whenever QuerySnapshotListener emits a value while ensuring that the QuerySnapshot and lastChanged field represent the same point of time i.e. they are part of the same batch operation. How to achieve this?
I have seen the snapshotsInSync() and waitForPendingWrites() functions but don't know how to use them for my purpose.
Edit:
The codes that I am using approximately are,
Client A
WriteBatch batch = firestore.batch();

DocumentReference<Map<String, dynamic>> lastChangedDocRef = firestore.doc("users/$uid");
FieldValue serverTime = FieldValue.serverTimestamp();

batch.set(lastChangedDocRef, serverTime);

DocumentReference<Map<String, dynamic>> docRef1 = firestore.doc("users/$uid/docList/doc1");
DocumentReference<Map<String, dynamic>> docRef2 = firestore.doc("users/$uid/docList/doc2");
batch.update(docRef1, {"dummyKey": "dummyValue"});
batch.update(docRef2, {"dummyKey": "dummyValue"});

batch.commit();

Client B
firestore
    .collection("users/$uid/docList")
    .snapshots()
    .listen((docChangeList) {

  firestore
      .doc("users/$uid")
      .get()
      .then((doc) {
    String lastChanged = doc.get("lastChanged") as Timestamp).toDate().toString()
    storeLastChangedLocally(doc.get("lastChanged"));
    storeDocChangeListLocally(docChangeList)
  });

});

Now consider this sequence of events:

Client A performs batch write as follows
lastChanged = 2:35:14
update doc1
update doc2


Client B reads
users/$uid/docList/doc1 updated
users/$uid/docList/doc2 updated
Client B about to read lastChanged


Client A performs another batch write as follows
lastChanged = 2:36:20
update doc3
update doc4


Client B reads lastChanged = 2:36:20 and stores it locally along with update doc1 and update doc2
Client B terminates for any reason

Here the local storage will be something like:
lastChanged = 2:36:20
update doc1
update doc2

When it should have been:
If client B terminated:
lastChanged = 2:35:14
update doc1
update doc2

If client B didn't terminate:
lastChanged = 2:35:14
update doc1
update doc2
lastChanged = 2:36:20
update doc3
update doc4


I'm not clear what the problem is that you're trying to solve.  It would probably help if you edit the question to show the code you have now and explain what isn't working the way you expect, or what the particular challenge is with extending that code to meet your needs.

@DougStevenson Ok I edited the question to add source code along with more context. I would really appreciate any help.

It is still not clear at which point you have a problem and what that problem is.
